# IdentityServer4 - redirects in Chrome stopped working

Tags: google-chrome, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have an implementation of IdentityServer (v3.1.4 nugets) running in ASP.Net Core 3.1.  On my dev machine (windows 10), Chrome will not redirect back to my Angular site after successful authentication, ie:

```
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
          _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
          return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        ...
```

If just ends up back at the login prompt.

Chrome Incognito also fails.
Clearing Chrome cache didn't help.
Rebooted a few times too.

Using FireFox works fine.
Also works fine in test and prod environments (Ubuntu host).
Also works on another dev's machine.

This has been working fine all year.  This started after a windows update last week. There was no code change to this part of the front end app or identity server for months.

returnUrl is like:

```
/connect/authorize/callback?response_type=id_token%20token&client_id=xxxxx.client.js&state=dXF2ZkFpRVFMTjNOY2JPcGxfVVJ3c1VqbXpleDVvU0xrNGRWZ1I1Uzzzzzz&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fauthenticate&scope=profile%20openid%20xxxxx.api.v1%20yyyyy.api.v1&nonce=dXF2ZkFpRVFMTjNOY2JPcGxfVVJ3c1VqbXpleDVvU0xrNGRWZ1I1UEpVQ3NH
```

I guess this is more of an annoyance than a shop stopper but it's convinced me to use Firefox for my main browser now - final straw for Chrome - it's is the new IE.

Comment: Try to post the failing redirect (request/response) in the question. Also if can be worth to make sure its not a SameSite issue https://www.thinktecture.com/en/identity/samesite/prepare-your-identityserver/

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved.  Chrome has been warning me about SameSite cookies for so long I had ignored them. Finally, it got sick of me ignoring it. :)